# Retrieving Data from Marvel's API in R (Error: is.response(x) is not TRUE)

Tags: r, rest, api, timestamp, authorization

I am trying to retrieve Data from Marvel's API with R. Yet my code looks like this:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
library(digest)

pb.txt <- Sys.time()
pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, tz = Sys.timezone)
time.stamp = strtrim(format(pb.date, tz = "GMT", usetz = FALSE, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"), 24)

public.key <- "***********************"

private.key <- "**********************************"

hash <- digest(paste0(time.stamp, private.key, public.key), algo = "md5")

url <- GET(paste("http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=", time.stamp, "&apikey=", public.key, "&hash=", hash, sep = ""))
```

The Error I get here is after:

```
> content(url) 

$code
[1] "InvalidCredentials"

$message
[1] "That hash, timestamp and key combination is invalid."
```

Beforehand the main problem was the timestamp, and I am still not sure if I calculate it the right way. 
Here is the [Documentation](http://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization) for the API.

I hope anybody with more experiences with APIs could help me.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I totally forgot. But the error now is:
    `$code
    [1] "InvalidCredentials"
    
    $message
    [1] "That hash, timestamp and key combination is invalid."$code
    [1] "InvalidCredentials"

    $message
    [1] "That hash, timestamp and key combination is invalid."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to bootstrap the parameters to the API requests (storing your keys in the fairly obviously named environment variables, best set in `~/.Renviron`):

```
marvel_hash_params <- function() {

  ts <- round(as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000) # can totally be just Sys.time(), too
  to_hash <- sprintf("%s%s%s",
                     ts,
                     Sys.getenv("MARVEL_API_PRIVATE_KEY"),
                     Sys.getenv("MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY"))

  list(
    ts=ts,
    hash=digest::digest(to_hash, "md5", FALSE),
    apikey=Sys.getenv("MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY")
  )

}
```

Then initialize them right away in your helper functions:

```
get_characters <- function(name) {

  params <- marvel_hash_params()
  params$name <- name

  res <- httr::GET("https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters",
                   query=params)

  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  httr::content(res, as="parsed")

}

get_characters("spider-man")
```

Even if you're not writing a full-on package, I'd suggest reading Hadley's [recommendations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/api-packages.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! Just need to figure out how to set the variables in .Renviron
And did you mean in the second function `marvel_hash_params()` instead of `marvel_hash()`?

Comment: aye, apologies. The entries in `~/.Renviron` are `KEY=value` : https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#renviron